# json_decode not working on WordPress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, curl

I am trying to get data from the API, I have the API URL and am getting data on my WordPress page in JSON format.

The problem is that I am not able to decode this JSON data, I had used `wp_remote_get( $curl )`,

`wp_remote_retrieve_body( $curl )`

```
$response = wp_remote_get( $curl );
$rows=wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) ;
json_decode($rows);
```

I had tried `json_decode($response )`, `json_decode($curl)` decode is not working with WordPress.

Currently I am getting data by writing `$row` into a `test.json` file and decode written on another PHP file outside WordPress, it's working.....

How can I decode inside WordPress?

Comment: the definition of json_encode in WordPress is wrapped by function_exists(). try to pass your json here: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: is that the complete code? you're missing your assignment

Comment: what do you mean by "not working". Do you get an error?

Comment: SORRY,i didnt get any error message,....

Comment: please check this url   http://plentyland.cordiacetechnologies.com/cms/api-part-2-testing/

Answer (score 4):

You can also use print_r / stripslashes / unserialize with your json data maybe json not formatted well.

```
$response = wp_remote_get( $curl );
$rows = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) ;
$decode = json_decode(stripslashes($rows), true);
//$decode = unserialize($rows); // you can try to use unserialize josn data in wordpress
print_r($decode);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply....
found message of :
Something went wrong: Operation timed out after 5000 milliseconds with 111142 bytes received      

i had already given on function.php

add_filter(‘http_request_timeout’, function(){return 100000000;});

Comment: because this not a proper url of the json also this url contains html code and json http://plentyland.cordiacetechnologies.com/cms/api-part-2-testing/

Comment: Operation timed because they have blocked your ip address.

Comment: http://plentyland.cordiacetechnologies.com/cms/api-part-2-testing/

please check the above url,
 i am getting data on that page as json format,
i just unable to decode it....

and here it is coded asper you mentioned
http://plentyland.cordiacetechnologies.com/cms/jsonchek/